# asp.net mvs Section within a Partial/Section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have some simple `<header>` stuff in the file Shared/_Header.cshtml.

My Shared/_Layout.cshtml inserts that code by calling

```
@Html.Partial("_Header")
```

This worked fine so far.

Now I have some views that, in addition to the normal output via the `@RenderBody()`, should also add some icons in a specific place in the header.

I use`@RenderSection()`in a couple of my views, to create a sidebar, etc.

Now my idea was to create a section within my view (e.g Home/Details.cshtml) and add a `RenderSection` call to the _Header. The Layout would call the Header, and header in turn would see if the section existed and call it.

However that doesn't seem to work. I get the following error/exception:

```
The file "~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.
```

Where lies my error? I know I can "nest" a partial call inside a section just fine. This code works just fine to tell the layout what file to use for a sidebar:

```
@section Sidebar{
    @Html.Partial("_SidebarDetails")
}
```

Does it not work the other way round?

I need way to define a block of HTML inside a view that is then put into a predefined place inside of a partial that is called by the layout.

Please help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a view contains a `RenderSection` it is considered to be a layout page and cannot be rendered directly. See this question for more info: [The file "~/Views/Position/Edit.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808377/the-file-views-position-edit-cshtml-cannot-be-requested-directly-because-it)

The easiest solution is to merge the partial view into the layout particularly if _Header.cshtml is only included on the layout page.

Another option is to override the header view with a custom header when needed.

In your layout page:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Header"))
{
    RenderSection("Header");
}
else
{ 
    @Html.Partial("_Header");
}
```

In your view (with custom icons):

```
@section Header
{
    @Html.Partial("_CustomHeader")
}
```

A further solution is to derive all your models from a base model class that contains custom icon data, e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public List<Icon> Icons { get; set; }
}

public class ModelWithIcons : BaseModel
{
     public ModelWithIcons()
     {
        // Set up icon data
     }
}
```

The _header partial view is (still defined in the layout page) will use this base model and, with null checks, render any icons it finds:

```
@model BaseModel

<!-- Header HTML -->
@if (Model != null && Model.Icon)
{
    // Render icons
}
<!-- More HTML -->
```

The obvious downside here is that all your models must derive from the BaseModel class or the partial view will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer and possible solutions. It helped me a great deal understanding.