# Asp.Net MVC5 Web Pages - using @RenderSection in _Navigation view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a _Navigation.cshtml view, to which I am trying to add some conditional `<ul> </ul>` tags using the Razor `IsSectionDefined()` and `@RenderSection()` directives.

However, I'm getting the following exception:

`The file "~/Views/Shared/_Navigation.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.`

As you can see in my below HTML snippet, I can add `@RenderSection("bobtest")` very easily into my `_Layout.cshtml` view, but NOT in the `_Navigation` view :

Snippet from ..\Views\Home\Index.cshtml :

```html
@section bobtest{
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse @Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards", cssClass: "in")">
    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Dashboard_1")"><a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard_1", "Dashboards")">Dashboard v.1</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Dashboard_2")"><a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard_2", "Dashboards")">Dashboard v.2</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Dashboard_3")"><a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard_3", "Dashboards")">Dashboard v.3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my _Layout.cshtml, which pulls in "_Navigation", "_TopNavbar", and "_Footer"

```html
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

            <!-- Top Navbar -->
            @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

            <!-- Main view  -->
            @RenderBody()

            @RenderSection("bobtest", required: true)   <!-- THIS WORKS... -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            @Html.Partial("_Footer")

        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->

    </div>
```

and here is a snippet from the `_Navigation` view:

```js
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
<div id="sidebar-collapse" class="sidebar-collapse">
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

 <li class="nav-header">

 <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Whatif")">
  <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard_1", "Dashboards")"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard">Current Portfolios</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
  @if (IsSectionDefined("bobtest"))
  {
   @RenderSection("bobtest", required: false)  
  }
 </li>
 
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

It will only cause an exception here, so I need some clarity on how to add conditional tags to my _Navigation view.

thanks,
Bob

Comment: Take a look at some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808377/the-file-views-position-edit-cshtml-cannot-be-requested-directly-because-it

Comment: Why not just use `@section` in the partial? ie `@section bobtest { //code here }`

Comment: @Ric - No, it does not render. Looks like it actually needs the @RenderSection() method.

Comment: `@RenderSection()` only works in layout views

Comment: @Ric - the first link you posted gave the answer. I created a separate cshtml partial, then pulled it inline to _Navigation.cshtml, i.e. `@Html.Partial("_NavPartial")` . This worked !

Comment: @Ric - please put your suggestions into an answer, and I'll gladly choose it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just upvote the linked answer that helped you - I just pointed you in the right direction :)